# What kind of Queries are considered NoneType in django?

Tags: python, django

I made a query to save data.

```
a = balance(name='MyName', income=50)
a.save()
```

Then I got,

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'save'
```

My code works fine without any problem.
My question is, why the object is considered `NoneType` ?

The Model is like:

```
class balance(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    income = models.IntegerField()
    date = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: The only object of type `NoneType` is `None` itself.  Something else is going wrong here - perhaps you overwrote the class `balance` with a function of the same name, that returns None...

Comment: Try changing the model name to Newbalance and migrate the database, it may be problem with name balance

Comment: I did not overwrite anything like this. @jasonharper

Comment: why it would be problem with balance? That's neither a reserved word(as far i know) nor clash with other functions of mine. @AnoopKGeorge

Comment: I copy your code in my machine and run, it did not give any error, so source of error for you from other code

Comment: Try deleting sqlite database and migrations and do again,

Comment: @AnoopKGeorge Thank you. Due to my projects consequences I can't do it now. But when possible, I will try to inform here if it fixes that thing.